# Swapping two rows of the same table based on ROWID in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

I have a table duty_rota. Which has following example set of data.

```
Rowid  duty_date   duty_type  duty_officer

   AA1    01-JAN-00    1             48
   AA2    02-JAN-00    3              5
```

Now I can retrieve the Rowid's and Swap the dates here. In my where condition there should be the rowid.

```
Rowid  duty_date   duty_type  duty_officer

       AA1    02-JAN-00    1             48
       AA2    01-JAN-00    3              5
```

Can somebody please help me, how could I achieve that through SQL query in oracle.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you care about the row's `rowid`?

Comment: When you say *rowid* do you mean oracle's pseudo column [rowid](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) ?

Comment: Yes that Rowid(pseudo column) is what I meant, I just edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: But why rely on rowid ? don't you have a primary key ? can't you use other more meaningful columns ? why does it have to stay with the same rowids ?

Comment: This database is ill designed there is no primary key, I have to use the rowid further in my application..that is why!!

Comment: I think you'd have to do this in a procedure, select for a date, then update one date, then update the other date.  (So about 3 separate statements minimum)

Comment: Can you please guide me how could I write it through a procedure please. @ebyrob

Comment: As I could understand you only want to order the registrys by the `duty_date` leaving all the other fields immutable?

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes it is...and non presense of primary complicates the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the merge statment to swap values between two rows in one sql command:

```
merge into duty_rota d
using (select * from duty_rota ) s
on ((d.rowid = 'AA1' and s.rowid = 'AA2') or (d.rowid = 'AA2' and s.rowid = 'AA1'))
when matched then update set d.duty_date = s.duty_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp_date DATE

SET @temp_date = NULL

SELECT duty_date FROM duty_rota WHERE ROWID = 'AA1' INTO @temp_date

UPDATE duty_rota 
SET duty_date = (SELECT duty_date FROM duty_rota WHERE ROWID = 'AA2')
WHERE ROWID = 'AA1'

UPDATE duty_rota 
SET duty_date = @temp_date
WHERE ROWID = 'AA2'
```

Or something like that, though I'm much more familiar with MySQL and SQL Server.